# fast opening and closing connection with a specific port

Tags: port, tcp, netstat

We have a Main application named "Trevor" installed in 2008R2 machine named "TEAMER12" which is slow now. One more application named "TVS" also running in  and found there were many connections per second occurring to port 5009.
netstat tool mentions that some fast connection open/close seen for port 5009
So first it will be listening mode like shown below

After that iwill become TIME_WAIT and i could see several entries like shown below

TCP    127.0.0.1:56658        TEAMER12:5009     TIME_WAIT

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:64181        TEAMER12:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED
```

again it will go several entries like TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:49156        TEAMER12:5009     TIME_WAIT

Can any body tell me whats the reason behind why many connections per second occurring to
port 5009 and why application slow?

Comment: What do you mean by "many connections per second"? That question seems to have come out of nowhere. Did you do a `netstat` twice a few seconds apart and see many connections in the second that weren't in the first? (As the output says, 0.0.0.0:5009 is the LISTENING socket.)

Comment: @avid Schwartz yes that was the one .Ok but now my question is why this entry " TCP 127.0.0.1:49156 TEAMER12:5009 TIME_WAIT " happening many times(around 100 times) and not establishing connection.Does this makes any issues for establishing connection with port5009

Comment: @avid Schwartz do we need to get rid of this waiting " TCP 127.0.0.1:49156 TEAMER12:5009 TIME_WAIT " by manupulating registry?

Comment: No! Why would you want to do something like that?! That's been understood to be a boneheaded thing to do since [1992](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1337).

Comment: @David Schwartz These are occurring on 127.0.0.1, I believe there have
been cases where all port numbers are used. So my question is how do you feel my netstat statics i posted nothiong abnormal?

Comment: it is not establishing with 127.0.0.1 ,but its establishing with real ip address TCP    172.26.127.42:64445    TEAMER12:5009     ESTABLISHED  ,why this is happening?

Comment: It makes no difference. Why do you think this is an issue?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Schwartzthe root issue is application TVS should do a operation with Main application Trevor by establishing connection with port 5009  , but thats not happening now. So i suspects issue is with port

Comment: Okay, so what *does* happen? Does it get an error?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz its not throwing any error, but the required action is not triggering. so i suspect port is busy and checked netstat entry and saw that around 60 times this entry  "TCP 127.0.0.1:49156 TEAMER12:5009 TIME_WAIT"   is happening

Comment: Your problem is the fact that the connections aren't doing whatever it is they are supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

All you've shown is that a reasonable number of connections are occurring and then those connections are closing. This may be perfectly normal or it may be abnormal. We don't know because we only know what you're telling us.

But the problem is that something isn't happening. If you can get logs of whatever it is that is supposed to do that something, perhaps they'll suggest why.

For example, the server might be closing the connection immediately. The client might be closing the connection without doing what it's supposed to be doing. The client might be sending the correct command but then the server closes the connection. You'll have to actually troubleshoot.

But all you've figured out so far is that a moderate number of connections are taking place.

Comment: yep,you may be correct i need to look trace files